# IE conditional statements

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I know this topic has been covered at length but I have tried many suggestions and not getting any results.  I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here,

```
<!--[if IE]>
<span class="itemt2e">Title</span>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
<span class="itemt2">Title</span>
<![endif]-->
```

which is located in the body, and in the head portion of the html

```
<style>
.itemt2e{font-size:14px;}
.itemt2{font-size:16px;}
</style>
```

Obviously the purpose is to make the font size 14px if the browser is any version of IE, and 16px for all other browsers (firefox, chrome, safari, etc.).  The code is showing up in the html but the browsers are not interpreting it since the word 'Title' doesn't show up in any browser.

Comment: How are you testing this? IE10 doesn't do conditions statements any more. And the 'emulation' option of IE10 doesn't actually respond to IE conditional statements. Crazy, I know. The only way to test this is on a computer with an actual version of IE9.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that.  So any version greater than 10 will not respond to this?  I tested with IE 11, but firefox, chrome, and safari weren't responding either.  So I am stuck with IE's interpretation of things?

Comment: Indeed, conditional comments are only for IE5 to IE9. Those are the only browsers that can read them.

Comment: IE11 mimics Firefox user string. There are still a few JS test to figure out if your in IE, and what version var isIE11 = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./);

Comment: Yes I think testing the user agent may be the route I go for now...

Answer (score 0):

Only IE(≤9) can understand conditional comments, so to all non-IE browsers, your second span appears to be within a normal comment block.

This is the correct conditional comment for IE:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<span class="itemt2">Title</span>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

This tells IE *not* to display the span, rather than trying to tell non-IE browsers to display it.

Edit: The text isn't showing up in IE for the same reason: IE10+ doesn't recognize conditional comments, and so it, too, thinks the span is in a comment.

Comment: Makes sense now.  Too bad since the font appears very large in IE, making the page look a bit off.